# Change html structure of regular price -> special price display on products listing

Tags: magento, themes, magento-1.7

When product hasn't set special price the product box looks like item 2. in the picture below (ofc except line-through price)

When product has special price it becomes to what you can see under item 1.

I want to change the HTML for products with special price from:

```
<div class="price-box">                            
    <p class="old-price">
        <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span>
        <span class="price"> 150 </span>
    </p>
    <p class="special-price">
        <span class="price-label">Special Price:</span>
        <span class="price"> 100 </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

to something more like:

```
<div class="price-box">                            
    <span class="old-price"> 150 </span>
    <span class="special-price"> 10 </span>
</div>
```

to obtain result as in the picture: from product box 1 to product box 2

both on main page (featured products, Incho) and serach listing.

[image]

Where to start? Where do I found necessary files?

Answer (score -1):

you can change in price.phtml file in your theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_theme/template/catalog/price.phtml
```

Comment: I don't have `price.html` in this location. In `catalog/` i have 2 folders : `category` and `product`. In `product/` i have 4 `.phtml` files but any of them is `price.phtml`. There is also `view/` folder which contains `price.phtml` but it does not affect to anything <- I think this is because mine regular price only `div.price-box` has already custom structure. I know there may be some XML files responsible for customizing . But I have no idea which ones